how to make cord fabric with geometry node?
hi does someone know how to make cord fabric like this with geometry node?

I try also with displacement texture, but sometimes it works not very well with some models
thanks !

Are you talking about the small-scale pattern of the fabric (material/displacement), or the general shape of it (modeling) ?

This is normal fabric with cord texture. Probably best to use the shader displacement to displace after GPU subdivision, but you can also just use the base surface as deform for a more complex surface.

It depends on that task and resources you have. You can apply normal map, procedural textures, parallax occlusion mapping, duplication or displacement real geometry. It all depends on the computing power of the system where it is realized and how much detail you need to obtain

@Lutzi I mean the pattern like wave texture, not the cloth shape

@MarkusvonBroady I tryed with displace, but the subdivision must be very high, or it will not look nice, if I zoom in. so i am thingking to make it with geometry nodes.

@Crantisz yes, I am working with rtx 4080, but it wokrs not very well if i turn the subdivision very high, so I am thinking if it will be better that I make it with geometry nodes.

Try Cycles experimental and adaptive subdivision.

blender was freezed, if I turn the subdivision of a sofa model to 5 or higher

There will be no difference if the geometry is generated with Geometry Nodes, for the same vertex-count.

Actually geometry nodes will be slower to render, because the vertices will be sent to GPU, while subdivision allows you to subdivide already on GPU.
However, in geometry nodes you can prepare such geometry that uses topology efficiently, the edges aligned to deformations. In practice, even without geonodes, you can have two planes, one for cloth simulation, and another with much higher resolution on only one axis - and then displace using some kind of wave, and then deform using the former plane.

@MarkusvonBroady thanks a lot. I just want try create the cord fabric with geometry nodes, i am curious about that. you mean, I can use edges align to create that?

there are 3 levels of detail here that you may aim for: 1) just a wave pattern going across one axis, 2) the fibers that are almost perpendicular to the ridges, barely visible on the reference, 3) the fluff achieved with a lot of hair. 1) is simple, 3) I think too but I don't have experience with hair, 2) is tricky.
